# Android intent-filter detect url with http get params

Tags: android

I want to make intent-filter which can detect urls like this one

http://x.xxxx.com/x.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com

but i only want detect it when the url has "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com"

does intent-filter can do this?

**Edit**

Here is the code i call the intent to start a url:

```
String url = "http://example.com/x.php?u=xxxx";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

And i tried this but it's not working:

```
<data android:scheme="http"  android:host="example.com" 
      android:pathPattern="/x.php?u=xxxx"/>
```

This also not working:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" 
      android:pathPattern="/x.php?.*"/>
```

However i tried only this can working:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" 
      android:pathPattern="/x.php"/>
```

I guess the problem here is that i can't contain the "?" characters in android:pathPattern
However i want it can be detected only when the query string u param contain "xxxx" string.

Does it can be solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:pathPattern in intent-filter in AndroidManifest.
Example:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/title_app">
     <data android:pathPattern="*xxx.com*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also there is another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490907/intent-filters-and-androidpathpattern)

In your case something like this

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="xxx.com"
      android:pathPattern="/x.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com" />
```

P.S. I think, that standard applications, such as YouTube and Google+ use the same method :)

**EDIT**

You can't parse query parameters with intent filter, answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277480/match-http-parameters-in-url-with-android-intent-filters)

I have read documentation about [`Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) and it says that according to [RFC 2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) **path** can't include "?" character

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain 
>   special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
>   their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>   purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>   reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>   forming the URI.
>
> ```
>   reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","
> ```
>
> The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that
>   are    allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a
>   particular component of the generic URI syntax; they are used as
>   delimiters of the components described in Section 3.
>
> 3  URI Syntactic Components
>
> `<scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>`

So, I assume that pathPattern is not applied to query part.

**EDIT 2**

Who creates intent, that you try to catch? You or another application?
May be you can send plain text intent without uri?

Comment: Thanks, but it still have problem, see my edit please

Comment: Hmm.. You can set last intent, catch it under debugger and see it's contents. At evening, I can help you with it, I have used such method in my application :)