# Android intent filter for a URL that ends with the given String

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, deep-linking

I am trying to open the app for links that look like this -

http://www.somesite.com/abcd.html?defg&opener=mail

I have tried (does not work):

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.somesite.com"                    
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPattern=".*opener=mail" />

            </intent-filter>
```

And for testing purpose it works without pathPattern added for any site that contains that host, but i need it to work only for this exactly site with "opener=mail" ending.

Comment: `android:pathPattern=".*opener=mail" />`. What is the function of that dot?

Comment: @greenapps I am not sure, I saw some examples where it was added, but even without "." it doesn't work.

Comment: As per the documentation: ["A period followed by an asterisk (".*") matches any sequence of 0 to many characters."](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Android can't see parameters or query strings, as it is already answered here - 
[Match HTTP parameters in URL with Android Intent Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277480/match-http-parameters-in-url-with-android-intent-filters)